# Using the C Preprocessor for code cleanup

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, legacy-code

I have a large, legacy C code base to look at, and there are lots of #ifdefs and #ifndefs throughout the code, mostly to maintain backwards compatibility with environments and operating systems that now no longer exist.

Is there any preprocessor-like tool that I could run this code through, that would take in all these C (mainly .c and .h, some .cpp etc) code and output set of source files getting rid of those blocks of code that would otherwise never be relevant? That would certainly make browsing the code easier for me, in addition to, perhaps cleaning it up in the in the long run.

Comment: "Using the C Preprocessor for code cleanup" - biggest oxymoron ever.

Comment: You can use `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `find` and your own stuff ^^

Comment: How would this tool know what pieces of code are relevant to you? In my opinion, all you'd get with automated tool would be nightmare of subtle bugs, because tool decided to remove little too much.

Comment: Every compiler has command line switch which allows to save preprocessor output to file. You can see the final code state there.

Comment: @Alex I don't think he wants `#include` expanded.

Comment: @AlexFarber Also, that would expand the macro's as needed on his current platform. He might still need others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/) for this. Read the ["About" page](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=about) and the [man page](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/coan_man_1.html).

The `spin` command can output your cleaned up sources under a directory of your
choice.